How to output the real-time logs of a shell script in Mac's Shortcut app?
I am trying to create a shortcut for Datastax (for Cassandra).
Datastax requires the execution of a shell script viz. server.sh to get the server started.
I am trying to create a "Run Shell Script" shortcut for the same. With the following command in the shortcut, the server starts, but I am not able to see the logs (real-time) while running the shortcuts (in Terminal I am able to see it however):
cd /Users/username/Downloads/datastax-studio-6.8.32/bin/
./server.sh

I am new to shell scripting (and Mac).
